# egrep incorrect matching?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I do

`egrep "[^e]" text.txt`

Where `text.txt` is:

```
hello
mellow
hello
wack
```

So precisely, shouldn't the output be `wack`?

but terminal (BASH) returns

```
hello
mellow
hello
wack
```

For some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a negative matching with `egrep`, you would need the `-v` option.

```
~]# egrep -v '[e]' text.txt
wack
~]# egrep '[e]' text.txt
hello
mellow
hello
```

In your command `^` inside `[e]` matches everything inside the input file except the `e`. For example, if your input file has a string `eeee`, then it would return everything except `eeee`

```
~]# egrep '[^e]' text.txt
hello
mellow
hello
wack
```

If you put `^` outside `[e]`, it wouldn't match anything because none of the strings inside `text.txt` begins with `e`.

Comment: So what does just `[^e]` do then? I don't understand it. If a word contains an e, thats okay?

Comment: It matches anything and everything except `e` in a string. It is useless if you have other characters inside a string besides `e`.

Comment: what if I want to filter out everything containing `e` with PURE regex? So not using the `-v` flags?

Answer (score 2):

`egrep` not needed here. To see what matched, you can use `--color=auto` option if available

```
$ grep --color=auto '[^e]' text.txt 
hello
mellow
hello
wack
```

You'll notice that all characters other than `e` were matched

Use `-v` option, it will return all lines not matching the given search pattern

```
$ grep -v 'e' text.txt 
wack
```

To modify OP's regex without using `-v`, need to match entire line

```
$ grep '^[^e]*$' text.txt 
wack

$ # or with -x if available
$ grep -x '[^e]*' text.txt 
wack
```

Comment: That does rather assume you've got a `grep` which will do coloration; not all variants of Unix have such a `grep`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for that tidbit, edited answer